# UK Carrera Vengeance Mens Mountain Bike -- I can't confirm mechanical disc brake pad sizes to replace

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes

I am trying to do something trivially easy and I can't find the information I need.

I need to replace the **mechanical disc brake pads** on my Carrera Vengeance Mens Mountain Bike. I bought some pads that looked right (visually) and found they're too big; the plates themselves don't fit/slide into the holding.

I have reviewed the bike stats page on the selling website (Halfords) and have reviewed various places online but nothing actually clarifies for me which dimensions of brake pads I should get for the bike.

My current brake pads measure 30mm x 18mm (W/H) and I need to replace these, I have already bought others that are slightly bigger and see various other ones that don't look right. Don't want to make the same mistake twice!

I'm looking at things [like these](https://www.wiggle.com/p/prime-shimano-road-disc-brake-pads#question/9053599) but these sales pages don't seem to give any specs on what they're actually selling (same for Amazon etc.)!

This is a stupid problem I can't believe I can't find the clear spec's for the replacement pads.

- If you have a Carrera Vengeance what pads do you use?
- Where can I find the Carrera Vengeance brake pad dimensions data?

Thanks

Comment: You dont use pad dimensions when buying pads, you use the make/model of brake caliper.  Update your question with your brakes and the pads you bought and i'm sure someone will be able to tell you the problem.

Comment: @AndyP I'm aware of that, but I don't know the make or model of the brake pads that are there and these specifications are not forthcoming on the seller website (Halfords) nor from google searching. They're probably some sort of shimano but I don't know which. If I have more info I would give it!

Comment: We dont need the make/model of the existing pads.  Just the calipers and the replacement pads you bought that dont fit

Comment: @AndyP ok, thanks, the calipers are "Indius" logoed and the bike sale page [Halfords] can be [found here](https://www.halfords.com/bikes/mountain-bikes/carrera-vengeance-mens-mountain-bike-2020---black---xs-s-m-l-xl-frames-340910.html) for reference if you want it.  Pads that don't fit are Shimano CFA614 (I think)

Comment: The halfords page you linked seems to show a tektro caliper.  Are yours different?  https://cdn.media.halfords.com/i/washford/340910h?w=1480&h=1110&qlt=default&fmt=auto&v=1

Comment: @AndyP yes, that's not the same one. But the capilers came on the bike from the shop so....

Comment: @AndyP **Correction:** The calipers are "radius". It's worn to fck and the wording wasn't clear.

Comment: Without knowing the model number it’s impossible to know. Is there any numbers or ID type info on the calliper? E.g one model of your brake brand  is Rom 6.0 which takes Shimano M505 pads https://www.populo.com/products/radius-rom-6-0-mechanical-disc-brake-caliper

Comment: https://www.halfords.com/cycling/bike-parts/bike-brakes/ebc-deore-hyd-525-disc-brake-pads-503823.html these fit many of this type of brake. Share a photo of your pads to be certain

Comment: @Noise it says on the specification / Pad size = 35mm which is too big. As stated, the pad plate needs to be 30mm.

Comment: What's the problem with taking one of the old pads to a bike shop?

Comment: @Noise where's the nearest bike shop? It's ages away and I'm more concerned how to find the right size of brake pad rather than simply delegating this task to a shop.

Comment: The problem you have is the brake is a chinese no-brand that uses a big manufacturer's pattern for the pad. The common patterns are Shimano Deore and Avid BB5, but there are others. There are so many shapes for all the brakes made to date, some of which are quite similar in dimensions, you understand why noone can give you a certain answer with the little information you've supplied

Comment: @Noise I was hopeful someone with a Carrera Vengeance could tell me the model of their pads , but as AndyP seemed to show, Halfords (now?) have different brake mechanisms on some Carrera Vengeance. This whole thing really shouldn't be this much hassle.

Comment: This type of brake could even have been changed midway through the year on this type of bike. Unfortunately this is one of the pitfalls of buying at this pricerange: it's not possible to fit brand name brakes where spares are easy to identify without raising the cost of the bike

Comment: Shimano pad designs are often used by other makes, and come in two main types (narrow and wide). A photo of the old pads (and their spring) along with the major dimensions would probably allow identification. Clear photos of the caliper might also help

Comment: @Noise whoever builds Carrera bikes may well dual source their brakes so even within a year it could be random rather than a switch. And even with big-name brands a change from one year to the next is possible; the difference is that Halfords documentation isn't up to finding out out anything other than the current version

Comment: I was too slow to edit: the dimensions of any hole or tab are also useful. I have a suspicion you need narrow type Shimano, but I could easily be wrong. I had some in my hand a couple of hours ago, with the wide type in the other hand (I thought the spares I'd bought for one bike would fit another but I was wrong) and the difference seems about right. But there are also less common rectangular styles. And if I google a brake pad model with "dimensions" I get the size of the packaging!

Comment: ... as my answer shows, I was wrong - it's wide type Shimano; narrow type must be about 26mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've got it.

Radius *hydraulic* brakes [apparently](https://www.unleadedbmx.com/en/radius-bh-m860-disk-brake-kit-7578.html) use a Shimano type B pad.  This is the "wide" type in Shimano's range.  Other brands make wider pads

Radius mechanical disc brakes are harder to find, but [this shop](https://www.populo.com/products/radius-rom-6-0-mechanical-disc-brake-caliper) says they take the same pads as a Deore M505.  That's a type B as well.  See this [compatibility chart for Shimano](https://shimanobikes-nz.prontoavenue.biz/ts1570079501/attachments/Page/20/Disc%20Brake%20Pad%20Compatibility%20Chart.pdf).

I have some compatible ones here.  These are Noah and Theos (a brand I've bought from a few times) NT-BP004s, and the other dimension is about 18mm.

[image]

Yours probably also use a split pin retainer.  That's another diagnostic.

Comment: Thanks so much, Chris, that's the type of info/reference I was looking for for what to get. Awesome!